# How to convert or replace the string "-" to bracket "()" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to convert or replace the string "-" to bracket "()" in vba ?

The original record there were three thousand.

| FILENAME | DESIRED FILENAME |
| --- | --- |
| 4715-(0).jpg | 4715(0).jpg |
| TC45-1.jpg | TC45(1).jpg |
| TC51-1b.jpg | TC51(1b).jpg |
| TC52-B-1.jpg | TC52(B1).jpg |
| WSO.19-A.jpg | WSO.19(A).jpg |
| N.WAB25-AF.jpg | N.WAB25(AF).jpg |
| WA.4-K1.jpg | WA.4(K1).jpg |
| PD.133-AFa.jpg | PD.133(Afa).jpg |
| KP02-10.jpg | KP02(10).jpg |
| 01-4-1-B.jpg | 01-4-1(B).jpg |
| 01-4-01-1.jpg | 01-4-01(1).jpg |

Comment: What problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: @braX , I can only do it manually with find and replace

Comment: I would start with the `Split` function, using the `-` as a delimiter, and then the last item will give you what needs parenthesis (remove the extension too with another `Split`). Then just rebuild the string, looping through the other pieces. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a go with a regular expression. Something like:

```
-\(?(\w+)\)?(\.\w+)$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBMNIr/1)

- `-\(?` - Match an hyphen and an optional literal opening paranthesis;
- `(\w+)` - A 1st capture group to match 1+ word-characters;
- `\)?` - An optional closing paranthesis;
- `(\.\w+)` - A 2nd capture group just to assert that previous matches are done before the extension. Here we match a dot and 1+ word-characters;
- `$` - End-line anchor to assert all previous matching is done at end of string.

You could chuck this into a VBA UDF and either call it from inside another sub *or* directly from th worksheet:

```
Public Function RegexReplace(s As String) As String

Static RE As Object: If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "-\(?(\w+)\)?(\.\w+)$"
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(s, "($1)$2")

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but there is one that is not yet appropriate . `TC52-B-1.jpg` should be the result `TC52(B1).jpg`  But with your function the result `TC52-B(1).jpg`

Comment: @user19541848 okay, I see what you mean. What is the logic compared to `01-4-01-1.jpg` which does not replace all hyphens?

Comment: sorry I'm late reply `01-4-01-1.jpg` for this one . It is in accordance with your function because the result is correct `01-4-01(1).jpg`

Comment: @user19541848 yes but why is there a difference in how many hyphens get replaced? What are your rules of logic?

Comment: thank for your answer, sorry I was late marking your answer